# How to disable ATI Stream Profiler plugin for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I've installed the ATI Stream SDK, which installed an add-on for Visual Studio without asking me. This addon creates an ATI Stream Profiler panel in Visual Studio.

How can I uninstall this profiler panel? (I still need the SDK, which is in use by an application).

Visual Studio doesn't list anything in the Add-in Manager or the Extension Manager. Are there any other places to check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ATI Stream Profiler is only installed if you selected the option to install the tool as part of the SDK installation.
To uninstall it, you can select the tool from the Windows's Control Panel, select the tool and uninstall.  This mode will be much safer than hacking the registry.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not an option in the SDK, you can still try to hack the registry, but this will be at your own risk.

VS packages information is stored in (64-bit machine, VS 2010):

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0

- The Editors subkey contains editors
- The OutputWindows subkey contains output windows
- The ToolWindows subkey contains tool windows,
- etc...

You'll have to browse this, find what's related to your ATI sdk, and remove it (or safer: rename). Good luck!